# How to Display Existing Files on Server in Dropzone JS?

Tags: javascript

In this blog, I will teach you how to display existing files or image on server in dropzone js. I will learn to show you existing image on dropzone js in php.
You can simply and easily to upload files or image on server using dropzone js. if you used dropzone js for uploading files and image then you might be need to show existing files or image from database using php mysql.

You will create just two files and one "upload" folder to make it done this example ,so just follow bellow example.

**Create Index.php File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>How to Display Existing Files on Server in Dropzone JS - NiceSnippets.com</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/dropzone.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/dropzone.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .dz-preview .dz-image img{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container" >
  <h1>How to Display Existing Files on Server in Dropzone JS - NiceSnippets.com</h1>
  <div class='content'>
    <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" >  
    </form> 
  </div> 
</div>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  $(".dropzone").dropzone({
    init: function() { 
      myDropzone = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {request: 'fetch'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
  
          $.each(response, function(key,value) {
            var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size};
  
            myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
            myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, value.path);
            myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
  
          });
  
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**Create upload.php File**

```
<?php
  
/* Upload directory*/
$targetDir = "upload/";
  
$request = "upload";
if(isset($_POST['request'])){
  $request = $_POST['request'];
}
  
/* Upload file */
if($request == "upload"){
  $msg = "";
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetDir.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $msg = "Successfully uploaded";
  }else{ 
    $msg = "Error while uploading";
  }
  echo $msg;
  exit;
}
  
/* Read files from */
if($request == 'fetch'){
  $fileList = [];
  
  $dir = $targetDir;
  if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
      while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
        if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
          $file_path = $targetDir.$file;
          if(!is_dir($file_path)){
             $size = filesize($file_path);
             $fileList[] = ['name'=>$file, 'size'=>$size, 'path'=>$file_path];
          }
        }
      }
      closedir($dh);
    }
  }
  
  echo json_encode($fileList);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: To get better answers, you might want to include a few additional pieces of info:

1. What is the expected behavior?
2. What behavior do you see? 
3. Have you tried any other steps to troubleshoot like reading documentation. If so, what have you found, and what happens when you try to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the internal function of react-native-weekday-picker mutates the same object (repeatDays in your case) passed to the library.
[see here](https://github.com/kuzdogan/react-native-weekday-picker/blob/3487c62126057fde2bbf8090840a6e32b7ecbfbb/WeekdayPicker/WeekdayPicker.js#L25)

and thought, you are setting a new state before rendering component the React compares prev value and current value but since it's of the same reference it doesn't rerender

```
const RepeatDaysHandle = (repeatDays) => {
    console.log(repeatDays);
    setWeekDays({...repeatDays});
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: let's be friends!

Comment: if u agree... pls contact me via skype or slack.

Comment: hey, @mankauto I don't use skype or slack. the links to other social media platforms are there on my profile

Comment: Hi Are you there?

Comment: yes, why did you modify the original question. instead of creating new one